# libmodbus modify default register offset

Tags: modbus

I have been testing a connection to a TCP modbus device using the open source libmodbus library.  The very first register I had to read was at 45001 on the device.  It turns out that using libmodbus I have to give it an address of 0 to get this register.  If I want register 45010 I use 9.

There is another register I want to read at 44001.  I don't see anything in the documentation about changing the base address.  Is it possible to use a negative offset?  Am I going to have to recompile the library?

Answer (score 2):

No, you're going to need to figure out how addresses described in your device's documentation map to actual Modbus addresses. This is *extremely* common.

The library you're using is just doing things the way the Modbus specification defines, and exposing that to you through its interface.